# Excel: How to convert "string" to a "number"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery

I have a user with a query from an SQL Database that returns a series of string in this form:

```
000123123.23000
000123123.23000
000123123.23000
000123123.23000
000123123.23000
```

These are really numbers, however they cannot be summed.  The correct way to fix this might be to cast the data in the SQL query, but then the Excel query viewer can't display it. As a workaround I do

```
 = <CELL> +1 -1.
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the value function can be useful for you

```
 = VALUE(< CELL >)
```

PD:

In spanish we use the function VALOR:

```
 = VALOR(< CELL >)
```

i think it should be the same on english

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  I thought there might be an eval() or such function -- but this is it!

Comment: glad to be helpful !!!

Answer (score 1):

I use this little macro

```
Sub txttonum()
    For Each tcell In Selection.Cells
        If TypeName(tcell.Value) = "String" Then
            tcell.Value = Val(tcell.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Which converts all the highlighted cells to numbers if they're strings

Comment: This won't work on a database query area unfortunately.

Comment: Good point, I don't think there's any way to fix the data in situ if it's coming from a query. I guess the value function is the best one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the VALUE-function did not work in my tsv-file.
But a small trick did the job:

1. select the column with the numbers in text-format
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> --> replace `.` with `,`

(Normally I would hate such solutions, but as said, I just post it here because the 'normal' way of solving it didn't work out for me.)

Comment: Karl, this answer has me stumped.  The only way I could see it working is if there is a locale variation where comma is used as the decimal delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your locale settings, VALUE() may return an error.

If that's the case, maybe [NUMBERVALUE()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879) can help you.

[VALUE vs NUMBERVALUE comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnVkD.png)

With a locale where decimal separator is a comma :

```
=VALUE("5,00") // Returns integer 5
=VALUE("5.00") // Throw an error

=NUMBERVALUE("5,00";",") // Returns integer 5
=NUMBERVALUE("5.00";".") // Returns integer 5
```

Comment: This is different than other answer why?